# How do you update NULL date fields to have 0000-00-00 in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update date fields that are NULL to have "0000-00-00" in them. I am trying:

```
UPDATE `results` SET `date_of_birth` = '0000-00-00' WHERE `date_of_birth` IS NULL
```

But when I simulate it, it says 0 matched records.  However, if I run this, it brings back 31 records:

```
SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `date_of_birth` IS NULL
```

Seems to be contradiction, or I am just missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: dont worry about the value in the table.  just translate null to 0000-00-00 when you run a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use any of the statement to update this which not contain a proper date value if this column has type date.

```
UPDATE `results` SET `date_of_birth` = '' WHERE `date_of_birth` = '' or cast(`date_of_birth` as date) is null or `date_of_birth` is null;

#With no strict mode.

UPDATE `results` SET `date_of_birth` = '0000-00-00' WHERE `date_of_birth` = '' or cast(`date_of_birth` as date) is null or `date_of_birth` is null;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out simulate query said 0, but when I actually ran it, it DID update 31 fields.  Not sure why that would happen. But thanks for the info nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql.mode

**To Check MYSQL mode**

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

[Refer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)